# Android tablet not auto-updating applications

Tags: google-play-store, application-autoupdate

I have an android tablet that is leveraging an internal company network. It appears that this device and all others similar to it are not auto-updating applications from the Play Store even though all the appropriate settings are correct.

I can see there are apps to update and I can even manually update an app but the auto-update never runs for any apps.

The same tablet in my home network will run the auto-update.

Could the companies internal network somehow be blocking the auto-update? If so how does the auto-update work so I can add exceptions to the firewall.

**UPDATE**

This device is a HP Slate 21 Pro All-In One and has both a WiFi and an Ethernet (wired) connection. We found that when the device is connected on the company network using a WiFi connection it DOES auto-update but it DOES NOT when connected using the ethernet connection.

My guess is that the Playstore (GMS) is checking if there is a WiFi connection and if so downloading the updates and if not a WiFi connection it does not download the updates. Similar to how a true mobile device behaves where there is either a wifi or cellular network connection.

Comment: Can you update manually? Do you get update notifications?

Comment: Yes, I can view my installed apps from the play store and it lists all those that have updates. I can then manually update them.

Comment: I didn't mean to *manually check*, but whether it retrieves update *information* automatically. What I'm after is possibly ruling out (or not) your company network blocking the port required by GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) to retrieve *incoming* information. To cross-check (and rule out it's that specific device/installation): Taking that tablet to your home network, does it work then there?

Comment: It am guessing it is retrieving the update information as when I view My Apps in the Google Playstore it states there is an update available, and yes the tablet works from my home network.

Comment: Could it be you disabled notifications for the playstore app? But that wouldn't explain the very same device working at home. I'm not sure how exactly it works, but it might well be for "passive notifications" (without the user triggering anything by e.g. opening the app), a separate specific port is being used (which might be blocked in the "corporate firewall").

Comment: Apparently this is a known issue and HP is aware of this. At this moment there is no fix for this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been reported to HP and has been confirmed it is an issue on their end or with the Play Store software.